# Registrar datos a DB y enviar mensaje por mail con PHP MySql desde HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, get

Me sucede lo siguiente.
Hice un formulario de contacto muy básico en HTML y envío esos datos de contacto por mail con el método POST.
El envío del mail funciona, pero no funciona la carga de datos en mysql.
Probé diferentes formas de código y conexión pero aparentemente la conexión está bien.
La consulta la llevo a PHP My Admin reemplazando las variables por datos  y me carga los datos correctamente.
El envío de mail lo hace correctamente, me llegan los datos al mail, con lo cual los datos estan llegando.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

https://resformatest.000webhostapp.com/

Este es mi formulario en el index.html

```
  <form class="formStyler" action="form.php" method="POST">

            <div>
                <label for="nombre">
                    <input class="formStyle" type="text" name="nombre" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input class="formStyle" type="email" name="email" required autocomplete="off"
                        placeholder="Email">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>

                <textarea id="text_box" class="formStyle" name="mensaje" required autocomplete="off"
                    placeholder="Message" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input class=" enviaMsg" type="submit" value="SEND">
            </div>

        </form>
```

**Este es mi form.php**

```
 <?php


  $name = $_POST['nombre'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
   $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

  $email_from = 'reforma.artdeco@gmail.com';

   $email_subject = "Nuevo Registro de Contacto";

   $email_body = "Usuario: $name.\n".
          "Email: $email.\n".
          "Mensaje: $mensaje.\n";
   $to = "reforma.artdeco@gmail.com";

   $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

   $headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

   mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);



   include("conexion.php");
   if (!$conexion) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

   echo "Connected successfully";

   $query = "INSERT INTO mailing (nombre, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')" ;
   $envio = $mysqli_query($conexion,$query);



    header("Location: index.html/#home");

    ?>
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero mientras revisas el error omitir el `header(...)` ya que puede allí aparezca el mensaje; en caso contrario mira en https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php para tu caso será la parte **Estilo por procedimientos** para que imprimas el error que obtienes (en caso de ser error). De momento lo importante es ver si es y que error.

Comment: Revisaste los logs de PHP? Revisa y edita tu pregunta con lo que encuentres en ellos

Comment: Gracias por el consejo!
Lo voy a probar, a ver que encuentro!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en tu archivo de conexion tengas algo como esto:

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "TUUSUARIO", "TUPASSWORD", "TU BASE DE DATOS");
```

Para que esa variable **$conexion** puedas utilizarla en cualquier lado

Entonces tu código quedaría de esta madera

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mailing (nombre, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')" ;
$conexion -> query($query);
```

Aplica la tecnica de "Divide y venceras"

Ya que comprobaste que los datos te estan llegando verifica tu conexion del lado de php. seguramente algo anda mal por ahi

Comment: Esta es mi conexión
<?php
$host = "";
$user ="";
$pass ="";
$db = "";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);





?>

Comment: De todas formas la conexión me da resultado exitoso.
Creo que la falla es en el envío de la consulta, pero no sé bien qué falla.

Comment: Intenta pasarla como te muestro en el ejemplo

Comment: Ok!
Ahora probaré eso!
Gracias!

Comment: Eso me funcionó!
Muchas gracias Nikola!